# Trying to make USB Drive Bootable with Ubuntu!

Tags: usb, mac, thinkpad

so I have an old IBM Thinkpad T42 I'm trying to be able to make boot to Ubuntu via a flashdrive (the laptop doesn't have a HDD.)

That being said my main computer is an iMac with OSX and that's how I'm trying to 
put ubuntu on to my flash drive so it can be then used to boot the Thinkpad.

I tried using the unebootin app for mac, but the thinkpad isn't wanting to boot to it still.

I made sure to go into the Thinkpad's Bios and set the boot order to go to USB first.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or have any suggestions? Thanks so much!

Comment: make sure to download the *desktop iso* file from here:  http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ or here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.10/ Also, for lubuntu: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/ or http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/current/ For xubuntu: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/daily-live/current/ or http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/14.04/release/ For ubuntustudio: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/14.04/release/ or http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/dvd/current/ There is also ubuntugnome and ubuntu mate.

Comment: I've found that older thinkpads don't seem to respect the listed boot order. I've usually still had to hit the blue think button then f9/f12 or whatever to choose what to boot first. And definitely just use `dd` to make the usb.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend avoiding Unetbootin UNLESS you REALLY need the persistent file, because it's generally way less reliable than `dd`. Run:

```
diskutil list
```

then plug in your flash drive. Then run it again and see which one is new, such as `/dev/disk2`. I'll use `disk2` for this example. Then unmount it so `dd` doesn't complain:

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2
```

Making sure to replace `disk2` with the disk you recorded.
You want to go to the directory that contains the Ubuntu image and do this command, but replace `diskX` with what I said earlier and ubuntu.iso with the iso image from Ubuntu:

```
dd if=ubuntu.iso of=/dev/diskX bs=2M
```

Then if you want to check the process, open another terminal and do `pgrep -l ^dd$`. Record the PID it outputs. Then do `kill -INFO PID` but replace PID with the PID that pgrep said.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the detailed instructions!

Comment: So I was able to bring up the terminal, see the flash drive and then unmount it using the command you gave me. I downloaded the Ubuntu iso and put it on my desktop. My only question though is how do I find the directory with the ubuntu image, or rather how do I bring up the desktop in the terminal so as to be able to execute that last command you gave me? Thanks so much!

Comment: @IanRocker In the terminal, do `cd Desk` and then press TAB then enter. Then do my steps.

Comment: Hey! So I did all those steps, but then upon hitting enter with the last command I received a message saying: "dd: dev/disk1/: Permission Denied"

Comment: Am I still doing something wrong?!?!

Comment: Make sure you're an administrator when running the terminal and that the file is accessible by the administrator. Also, append a / to it, so dev/disk1 would be /dev/disk1 .